Sound imtermittent (random silent gaps) on new 24.04 installation
I have a newly installed (from ISO) Ubuntu 24.04 machine, and the sound is intermittent when coming though HDMI. It cuts off at irregular intervals, so I get maybe half a second of silence every 2-5 seconds, it's fairly random.
It's happening through both local media that I know has good audio, as well as through Netlix and YouTube. It only seems to happen when played through HDMI, not the local speakers.
I've tried restarting and tried locally through both VLC and the standard Videos.
I should also mention this laptop is ~10 years old, the setup I have now (i.e. laptop plugged into this TV) worked with my last distro (Linux Mint) as well as previous Ubunutu versions, I don't remember having anything like this sort of problem with HDMI audio.
Any help appreciated!
